# Passing an Array from one UseState to Another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-dnd

I'm currently trying to figure out how to pass an array from one useState object to another across two different components. In my first useState I have an array called `imagesOriginal`, which gets filled with file paths dynamically to various different images like in the following:

```
[
    "https://source.unsplash.com/WLUHO9A_xik/900x900",
    "https://source.unsplash.com/R4K8S77qtwI/900x900",
    "https://source.unsplash.com/jJGc21mEh8Q/900x900"
]
```

In my `App.js`, I construct it like so.

```js
import React, { useCallback, useState } from 'react';
import ShowImage from './ShowImage.jsx';
import DropBox from './DropBox.js';

function App() {
    const [imagesOriginal, setImages] = useState([]);

    const onDrop = useCallback((acceptedFiles) => {
        acceptedFiles.map((file, index) => {
            const reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                setImages((prevState) => [
                    ...prevState,
                    { id: index, src: e.target.result },
                ]);
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            return file;
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div class="parent">
                <div>
                    <h3>Originals</h3>
                    <DropBox onDrop={onDrop} />
                    <ShowImage images={imagesOriginal}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

The main issue comese in the `ShowImage.jsx`, where I want to pass that array of images to another useState, as I need to use both the array and the setItems to sort the array with a new order.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
    DndContext,
    closestCorners,
    MouseSensor,
    TouchSensor,
    DragOverlay,
    useSensor,
    useSensors,
} from '@dnd-kit/core';
import "./ShowImage.css"
import {arrayMove, SortableContext} from '@dnd-kit/sortable';
import {SortablePhoto} from './SortablePhoto.jsx';

const ShowImage = ({images}) => {

    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    setItems([...images]);
    const [activeId, setActiveId] = useState(null);
    const sensors = useSensors(useSensor(MouseSensor), useSensor(TouchSensor));

    return(
        <div class="scroll">
            <DndContext
                sensors={sensors}
                collisionDetection={closestCorners}
                onDragStart={handleDragStart}
                onDragOver={handleDragOver}
                onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}
                onDragCancel={handleDragCancel}
            >
                <SortableContext items={items} strategy={() => {}}>
                    <div columns={1}
                        style={{
                        display: "grid",
                        gridAutoRows: `100px`,
                        gridGap: 10
                        }}
                    >
                        {items.map((url, index) => (
                            <SortablePhoto key={url.src} url={url.src} index={index}/>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </SortableContext>
            </DndContext>
        </div>
    );

    function handleDragStart(event) {
        setActiveId(event.active.id);
    }
    
    function handleDragOver(event) {
        const {active, over} = event;
    
        if (active.id !== over.id) {
          setItems((items) => {
            const oldIndex = items.indexOf(active.id);
            const newIndex = items.indexOf(over.id);
    
            return arrayMove(items, oldIndex, newIndex);
          });
        }
    }
    
    function handleDragEnd(event) {
        setActiveId(null);
    }
    
    function handleDragCancel() {
        setActiveId(null);
    }
};

export default ShowImage;
```

I've tried using the line `setItems([...images]);` to try and pass the new items in, and also `const [items, setItems] = useState(images);`, but It never seems to update the `items` array. I'm probably doing something really stupid, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where do you populate this empty state in `app.js`?

Comment: I've added the bit of code where I add to the array, sorry for omitting that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a function in your `App` component that wraps your `setItems` state modifier and pass this function as a prop to your nested `ShowImage` component where you could use it to manipulate the state. This way you won't need to maintain 2 different states.

```js
// App.js

function App() {
    const [imagesOriginal, setImages] = useState([]);
    const setImagesWrapper = useCallback(val => {
      setImages(val);
    }, [setImages]);
    //...

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div class="parent">
                <div>
                    <h3>Originals</h3>
                    <DropBox onDrop={onDrop} />
                    <ShowImage 
                      images={imagesOriginal} 
                      setImages={setImagesWrapper}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

```js
// ShowImage.js

const ShowImage = ({ images, setImages }) => {
    const [activeId, setActiveId] = useState(null);
    const sensors = useSensors(useSensor(MouseSensor), useSensor(TouchSensor));
    // ...
};

export default ShowImage;
```

Comment: Yes, having the same data in two states is always a bad idea

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering if there was a way to pass the SetItems as a prop but wasn't exactly sure. Thanks for the clarification and the note about having the same data in two states.

Comment: Sorry, one more question. How would I use the setImages with the prop? I'm able to use the images through the prop but I'm not sure on the other part.

Comment: I have updated my answer. As you can see in my code I created a wrapper based on the state setter and passed it to the ‘ShowImage’ component so you could simply get it from the props object of your functional component.